# Help building a query with related to

Tags: craft3, craft4, yii

I'm trying to create an or query with 2 related fields and 1 title field.
My version so far is this:

```
$searchQuery->where([
    'or',
    ['relatedTo', 'targetElement' => $ids, 'field' => 'field1'],
    ['relatedTo', 'targetElement' => $ids, 'field' => 'field2'],
    ['like', 'title', $search]
]);
```

But with that query I keep getting the error:
`Undefined array key 0`

$ids is not empty.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think `relatedTo` should not be used in that place, but should be used on the `$searchQuery` object instead:

```
$searchQuery
  ->relatedTo([
    ['field' => 'field1', 'targetElement' => $ids],
    ['field' => 'field2', 'targetElement' => $ids],
  ])
  ->search('title:' ~ $search);
```

That being said, this would not give you the results that I think you're looking for (elements related to the $ids, OR with the title you searched for). To be honest, I don't think this can be done with one query, but maybe someone else knows the trick?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply but that solution is idd an AND not an OR. I used a workaround to get it to work. I posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

Used an two step workaround by splitting it in 2 queries, merging the ids and searching by id in a 3rd query.

```
$searchUsersIds = User::find()->search($search['rawSearch'])->ids();

$searchUserResultIds = [];
if(!empty($searchUsersIds)) {
    $searchUserQuery =  clone $searchQuery;
    $searchUserQuery->relatedTo(
        ['or',
            ['targetElement' => $searchUsersIds, 'field' => 'field1'],
            ['targetElement' => $searchUsersIds, 'field' => 'field2']
        ]
    );

    $searchUserResultIds = $searchUserQuery->ids();
}

$searchCompanyQuery = clone $searchQuery;
$searchCompanyResultIds = $searchCompanyQuery->search($search['rawSearch'])->ids();

$companyEntryIds = array_merge($searchUserResultIds, $searchCompanyResultIds);

if(!empty($companyEntryIds)) {
   $searchQuery->id($companyEntryIds);
}
```